# 'logIn': identifier not found

Tags: c++, methods, compiler-errors

This question is probably already answered but I can't find it so just comment the link. 
I think the problem is that the compiler isn't reading the other method and stopping once i call it.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void mainMenu() {
    system("cls");
    cout << "===== Main Menu =====" << endl;
    cout << "1. Log In" << endl;
    //cout << "2. Date and Time" << endl;
    cout << "3. Exit" << endl;

    int minput;
    cin >> minput;

    switch (minput) {
    case 1: logIn();
        break;
    default: mainMenu();
        break;

    }
    system("pause");
}
void logIn() {
    string npassword;
    ofstream outfile;

    system("cls");
    cout << "Log in > " << flush;
    string password = "testing123";
    bool notLoggedIn;
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    while (notLoggedIn = true) {
        if (input == password) {
            cout << "Login Succeful" << endl;
            mainMenu();
        }
        else if (input == "-fp") {
            outfile.open("passwordlist.txt");
            cout << "Enter your new password > " << endl;
            cin >> npassword;
            outfile << npassword << endl;
            outfile.close();
            logIn();
        }
        else {
            cout << "Incorrect Password. To reset your password type -fp " << endl;
            system("pause");
            logIn();
        }
    }
}
int main() {

    mainMenu();

    return 0;


}
```

:
Here is the error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Category    Suppression State
Error   C3861   'logIn': identifier not found   Project1    c:\users\user1\documents\c++\project1\project1\source.cpp   17

I don't know hap to fix this. I am new to c++ so any help would be nice!

Comment: You need to declare functions before you can use them (e.g.: by using a forward declaration) - add `void logIn();` before `void mainMenu()`

Comment: I tried that already. It gives me the same error but says mainMenu identifier not found

Comment: then you didn't do what I said. Don't move the entire `logIn` function, just add that one line right before the `mainMenu` function

Comment: Thanks I'm so dumb. I can't even read English. Anyways thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use `logIn()` before it is declared.  You can solve this by adding a forward declaration prior to `mainMenu()`:

```
void logIn();

void mainMenu() {
...
}

void logIn() {
...
}
```